# Soap Exception error..Server was unable to process the request

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I am working on asp.net and Oracle and using a Web Service. Sometimes I get this error:

> System.web.services.protocols.soapexception: Server was unable to
>   process request.. --> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference
>   not set to an instance of an object.

The main thing is I am not getting this error every time. But sometimes it comes and sometimes not. And also with the same data every time.

I don't understand why it is like that. If I am not doing something right, then it should come all the time.

Please help.

Comment: With NullReferenceException's your most valuable tool to locate a cause is the stack trace. At best it will give you a line number (if the PDB files are deployed) at worst it will give you a method name.

Answer (score 0):

> > I don't understand why it is like that. If I am not doing something right, then it should come all the time

A system with at least two independently functioning entities will never be repeatable. Timing will always be an issue. At best you can reduce the timing down to a negligible difference. In this specific case its possible that a section of code assumes a request or response had completed before continuing because in 99% of the time that request or response completed within a small time window.

Good luck! These are alway the hardest type of bugs to track down.

Comment: As the program has to read, send data to web service, retrieving output from web service and updating database. And there are 1000 records and the time program takes is 10 min for all the records. So should I try to reduce this time for this error to go away (please do not consider performance)?

Comment: The total length of time it takes to complete your program is unlikely a factor in this case unless you are trying to send a single 10 minute long request. It is much more likely that a single request/response is failing due to a timing issue. If you can locate the line of code where the null exception occurs you may be able to add check and retry that will allow you to retry that individual request.

Answer (score 0):

The NullReference exception is hard to track as the stated above.

Do you have an idea where in your code this problem occurs?

Can you reproduce the error yourself this occurs again? Or does another retry solve the problem? The stacktrace of the exception object should give you a Method name.

This should help you out with the problem.

Good luck!

Comment: I have tracked down the stack trace. But according to me, there was nothing useful there. I'll still look into that. But my question is if i am not sending some value or something else, then the error should come every time but it is not. Then what can be the matter? Let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: It depends. What does the method do? Post the code and the stack trace and let's gave a look.